# Analysis Tools to help you in C development

Tags: c, static-analysis

I've just started learning C and I have a hard time finding bugs, memory leaks and the like. Which are good tools to assist you in finding such things? I heard of Valgrind but are there others?

Comment: Well, there's your debugger ;v) . What platform are you on?

Comment: +1 @Potatoswatter, if you just started, a debugger is more than enough to find the bugs you'll have.

Comment: I'm working on Ubuntu and Solaris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me (on Linux) there are:

- [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) used to find bugs
- [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) find memory leaks

Answer (score 1):

If you're allocating memory dynamically your programs are probably already too complex for it to do a really good job, but you may be amused by the value analysis in Frama-C. Take a look at the [tutorialet](http://frama-c.cea.fr/try_out.html) and move up to the tutorial chapter in [the manual](http://frama-c.cea.fr/download/value-analysis-Beryllium-20090902.pdf) if you are still interested.

Answer (score 1):

[lint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29) is the classic C static analysis tool.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect they cost more than you’re willing to pay, but both Coverity and Klocwork do serious checking for memory leaks, along with lots of other things.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind catches a lot of memory errors.  It misses a variety, too, such as access outside of a local array.  Our [CheckPointer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety) tool will catch virtually all types of bad memory references at the moment the error is made.   See the comparison table at the web page to see more things Valgrind won't catch that CheckPointer will.